# Find equation of tangent line to a curve $g(x)$ at $x=4$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I am trying to find the equation of a tangent line to the curve: $$y = g(x)\text{ at }\,x = 4$$

given $g(4) = -6,\;$ and $\;g'(4) = 2$.

Comment: $g\prime(4)$ is your slope, and you have a point.

Comment: You are given both the slope and a point of the line.  Use the point-slope form to get the equation.

Answer (score 4):

The tangent line is $$y-g(4)=g'(4)(x-4)$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $g(4) = -6$, tells us that when $x = 4$, $g(x) = -6$, so the line passes through the point $(x_0, y_0) = (4, -6)$.

Since $g'(4) = 2$, the slope of the tangent line at $(4, -6)$ is $\;m = g'(4) = 2$.

Using the point-slope form of an equation, we have $$y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$$
In this case, it is the line $$y - (-6) = 2(x - 4)\iff y + 6 = 2(x-4)$$